# Failed to verify code signature of... Can't install application on my iPhone

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I can't install my app to my iPhone using this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos

I do everything like this, but it shows this error in console

```
 VerifyingApplication - PercentComplete: 40%
 ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of....: 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
error MT1006: Could not install the application '..' on the device 'iPhone': Read Error (error: 0xe8000004)
```

P.S I connect my iPhone via network

Answer (score 2):

Have a try with checking Bundle Signing and [Enabling Automatic Signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=windows#enabling-automatic-signing) :

1. Pair Visual Studio 2019 to a Mac as described in the Pair to Mac guide.
2. In the **Solution Explorer**, right-click the project name and **select Properties**. Then, navigate to the **iOS Bundle Signing tab**.
3. Select the **Automatic Provisioning scheme**:

[image]

4. Select your team from the **Team** combo box to start the automatic signing process.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Checking Custom properties as Entitlements.plist helped me